# XML XSD - noNamespaceSchemaLocation alternative location conditional

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

I have an xml for which I suggest a custom schema after which it validates the xml like this:

```
<testrun xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="mySchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" date="Jul 26 2016" time="12:40:37">


<testrun xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://server_name:10000/nexus/service/local/repositories/myDirectory/content/mySchema.xsd"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" date="Jul 26 2016" time="12:40:37">
```

Unfortunately up till now I can either go with one or the other.

What I'd want is to specifiy the site like in the second example and, if the site is down, to go with a local xsd schema in the project where I have the xml file.

So something like: if it can obtain the schema from the site, get it from there, else get it from a local file.

How can I place a conditional like that?

Comment: It seems to me that this is quite the job of an xml catalog [tag:xmlcatalog]

Comment: Interesting, I had never used an XML catalog before, but I'll give it a try. Know any tutorial sites that deal with setting up multiple schemas for noNamespace nodes?

Comment: I think you can have a look at the [tag info on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlcatalog/info) or to [this resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlcatalog/info)